Python json.load Decode Error Expecting ':' delimiter
So I have a massive .json file containing a dictionary. It looks basically like this:
{"[deleted]": {"8gwmc": 1241136488, "8gtzp": 1241116576, "8gogw": 1241098644, "8gwtz": 1241151485, "8emcn": 1240428839, "8h190": 1241184318, "8gmme": 1241066851, "8h1rn": 1241188147,

I'm reading it with the following code:
with open(AP_string, 'r') as AP:
    Astamps = json.load(AP)

This has worked for a bunch more files just like it, but this one has a problem character and throws the following error:
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting ':' delimiter: line 1 column 78175081 (char 78175080)

So this appears liked an issue with some kind of escape character in the data. The file is too large to be opened by a text editor so I can only attempt to access or edit it through code. I'm not sure how to find/isolate/edit the problem character which I'm sure is one potential solution.
I have tried using json.loads instead and first reading it as a string to try to perform a unicode escape on it (this throws an error) or to read it as a raw string. This causes json.loads to throw an error expecting a value at line 0 character 0.
I have tried for load/loads setting strict = False to no effect.
Update: Problem "solved" Turns out the file was borked to begin with.

Try printing out a piece of the file around the character number that it gives you? Since you're able to load it into memory, something like: print(s[78175040:78175120])

BTW, one guess — how big is the file? If it's about 74-75MiB, it may be that that's the end of the file and the rest is just missing

@JiříBaum Strange... seems the following is repeated a bunch '^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^'

Since you used the file-like object approach, have a debugger (e.g. pdb.post_mortem()) and .seek() to the appropriate spot in the file and attempt to see what the bytes actually are, because a bunch of repeating characters shouldn't cause the problem if it's double-quoted as a string.

The section that looks like this appears to extend quite a ways back, trying to find the beginning

^@ is probably the ASCII NUL character (you can check by using ord()), which shouldn't appear in a JSON file at all, so the file may be corrupted

Yep, just finished tracking it down myself, that does appear to be the issue. Thanks!

Please answer below rather than update the question

Sometimes a failure to flush a buffered file to disk results in nulls at the ending sectors of the file.  It sounds like this is the case and this question can be deleted since it was due to a corrupt file.  An answer is not necessary.

Turns out the file was corrupted. Not an issue with the code at all.
